# How to pass selected filename to controller to process in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rails-activerecord, rails-activestorage

I want to select a zip file on local computer and process it before adding to database.

I've got the controller working to do all of this except pass in the filename. It works if I put in the filename manually.

```
<%= form_with model: @bp, url: { action: "import_data" } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :health_exported_zip %>
  <%= submit_tag( "Import" ) %>
<% end %>
```

`bp_controller`

```
def import_data
  # Following line errors
  health_exported_zip_file = params[:health_exported_zip] # no implicit conversion of nil into String
  # Manually setting file location which works with the above line commented out
  health_exported_zip_file = "/Users/username/Downloads/export.zip"
  unzip_import_data(health_exported_zip_file)
  …
end

def unzip_import_data(health_exported_zip_file)
  require 'zip'
  unzip_to =  "import_staging"
  …
end

# Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
def bp_params
  params.require(:bp).permit(:statdate, :systolic, :diastolic, :heartrate, :sourceName, :sourceVersion, :comment, :health_exported_zip)
end
```

This must be simple to do, but I'm at a loss. ActiveStorage using similar `form_with` must have access to the file when file uploading. Thank you

So not simple, but @masasakano pointed me to reading `params` which I parsed as follows to get path to the temporary copy of the zip file.

```
indexTempfile = params.to_s.index('/var/folders') # setting start of Tempfile location
tempfile_path = params.to_s.slice!(indexTempfile..450) # slice off the beginning of params
indexEnd = tempfile_path.to_s.index('>') - 1 # get end of Tempfile location. 
tempfile_path = tempfile_path.to_s.slice!(0..indexEnd) # slice off the end of params and left with path
```

`tempfile_path` is what need as `health_exported_zip_file`. Renamed since it's not the original file.

Comment: In the controller, do you process `params` with `require`? Could you include the part to pre-process `params` in your Controller, if there's any?

Comment: Don't do this in your controller -- create a service that takes a file.  I am guessing that `unzip_import_data` takes a path -- it should take a file, because you are not going to get a path on an upload.  You will just get the bytes from the file.

Comment: @dbugger I look into to that. OK, services are cleaner code, but it should still be doable in the controller. Yes `unzip_import_data` takes path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `params` returns is an [ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) object (see [Official reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)). So the returned value of `params` is **not** the filename as you manually set with `unzip_import_data(health_exported_zip_file)`.

Instead you can use `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip].path` (which is an alias of `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip].tempfile.path`) to get the path of the uploaded file, which you can feed to your unzip function.

So, that is a problem I have noticed.

However, if the exception you encounter is `no implicit conversion of nil into String` as you state, then I guess `params` has failed to pick up the uploaded file in the first place and then `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip]` returns `nil`. There are numerous potential causes for it, such as, you actually didn't uploaded a file in your attempt (even though you think you did), or the uploaded file exceeded the maximum permitted size, or the controller is not called from the view as you intend, etc…

My advice is to dump `params` in your particular case to see what is passed to your controller as a starting point of your investigation.

**[Edit]**
After exchanging comments, it turned out the pre-filtering method the OP included in the Controller is **not** called in the OP's test case. Then, `health_exported_zip` is filtered out from `params` because of Rail's strong parameter constraint, and `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip]` would return `nil`.  So, you should add `:import_data` in the `only` clause in your `before_action` to call the pre-handing method. Alternatively, a more direct way is to add the line of your chosen `params.permit` etc at the head of the `import_data` method.

Comment: Got it. params: 
{"authenticity_token"=>"eYPsSV5XsnshfVc45rbUA7TsYNZ-Jkl35FM9qYuykNbNkxXvT_90bi-f8VwPi348OEx1dnyTKKKELfWGSjHCcA", "bp"=>{"health_exported_zip"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fbe22949ca0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/f6/…/T/RackMultipart20211224-13925-a8cgl1.zip>, @original_filename="export 2.zip", @content_type="application/zip", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bp[health_exported_zip]\"; filename=\"export 2.zip\"\r\nContent-Type: application/zip\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Import", "controller"=>"bps", "action"=>"import_data"}. Copied to `var`

Comment: I can't yet figure out the syntax to get `Tempfile`.

Comment: `params[:health_exported_zip].tempfile` returns a `Tempfile` object. See the official references – the two links are embedded in my answer!

Comment: Thank you. I had read your refs, but couldn't figure out how to get the path. I used Ruby strings to parse `params` to get the path. So I've got what I need, but don't know how robust it is. But it works.

Comment: Didn't `params[:health_exported_zip].path` (as in my answer), which is an alias of `.tempfile.path`, return the path in String? I have never used it, but the reference indicates so…

Comment: `puts params[:health_exported_zip].path` => `NoMethodError - undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass:`

Comment: Are you sure `bp_params` is definitely executed before `import_data` is run? The fact `params[:health_exported_zip]` returns `nil` suggests the parameter cannot be accessed via the `[]` method **because of** Rail's strong parameter constraint.

Comment: My naivety on Rails. I had `before_action :set_bp , only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]` which errors without the `only`. I need to figure out what should be going on. Thank you for following up. This is pretty much a personal app, but still should get it right.

Comment: That explains. `bp_params` is never executed in your test run!  I added the explanation of the likely cause and solution in my answer. Have a look and try it.

Comment: Read the docs again `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip].tempfile.path`. Don't know if it would be misleading to mark the answer as correct, but it was close. I went back because the patch is different on the server and realized I needed to figure it out rather than hacking. Thank you

Comment: `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip].path` is an alias of `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip].tempfile.path` according to the reference. They should be identical providing the file exists.

Comment: I should have pointed out that what is different is the `[:bp]` was missing. I'll try the alias. I'm now figuring out to use the /tmp folder to process the file.

Comment: Good point! I have edited my answer to correct the points. Hope you will figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep the `params[:bp][:health_exported_zip].tempfile.path` to better remind me of what's going on. The alias obfuscates it a bit. And I don't have to write this very often. I think I've figured out the rest. Debugging now